# Adding two columns in pandas.dataframe using assign, and get error message said KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, csv

I was trying to add few more columns in my datagram, but I got an error message saying that KeyError: ‘H00——01——TC’， which is a column's header in my CSV, is there any way to fix it? Thanks, guys

```
 LD = pd.read_csv(Y21_DM, header=0,low_memory=False)

 CR = pd.read_csv(Crash_Rate, header=0,low_memory=False)

TOTAL = LD.merge(CR, left_on = ['LINKTYPE','SPEEDLIMIT'], right_on = ['LINKTYPE','SPEEDLIMIT'])

aaa = TOTAL.assign(H00_01_TC_ALL=(TOTAL['H00_01_TC']+TOTAL['H18_07_IXD'])/60)

print(aaa)
```

and here are the error message I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'H00_01_TC'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Learning/Python/BCR.py", line 121, in <module>
    aaa = TOTAL.assign(H00_01_TC_ALL=(TOTAL['H00_01_TC']+TOTAL['H18_07_IXD'])/60)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'H00_01_TC'
```

Comment: Whelp, the message basically says that column 'H00_01_TC' seems to be missin for some reason.Are you sure it exists in 'TOTAL'?

Comment: Thank man, I think you are right...I miss-spelled the Column name...

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this code to see the list of columns, Then check if column 'H00_01_TC' exist or if there is a problem with the spelling.

```
TOTAL.columns
```

Comment: Thank you Ian, Looks like I miss spelled my Column's name...